# Angular $templateCache and $stateProvider fix for native ios phonegap/cordova

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-templatecache

Angular $templateCache, $stateProvider and ng-include works beautifully in a web browser, but on native ios using phonegap/cordova it won't load templates or go to states

I've gone through the checklist:

- remove `<base href="/">`
- make sure paths are relative "template.html"
  vs "/template.html"
- make sure html5Mode is false
- load templates.js before angular
- make sure dependency injections are in place

Here are some examples of what works in a browser but not on native ios.

```
$stateProvider.state('start', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'templates/start/start.html'
});
```

and

```
$state.go('start');
```

and

```
<div ng-include=" 'fileFromTemplatecache.html' "></div>
```

Any idea? I can't find a solution that works.

Comment: It should work normally, something is either wrong with yout paths or with your project setup. Maybe screenshot of your project folder structure would help

Comment: Thanks, @FranePoljak - it was a config issue. I added my solution below.

Comment: For the iOS  you can check the error in the Safari -> Developer -> select device/simulator(where your app is runnign) -> Index.html
Hope this helps you in debug the error more easily next time

Answer (score 0):

Others will come across this issue I'm sure. The solution has to do with the config.xml file at the root of your mobile build. This is what worked for me...

```
<allow-navigation href="file://*/*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="file://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<access origin="file://*/*"/>
<access origin="*"/>
```